# Pivot table Date Filter- Force 'This Week' to Monday

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

Using a pivot table with dates as row labels I can select to 'Filter Date' by 'This Week'.  However, this week runs Sunday to Saturday, and I would prefer to see Monday to Sunday.  Is there a way to force the week start?

I would prefer if the answer did not use vba, as this is for a colleague, but am happy to use it if necessary.

Any solutions appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a global setting, I don't think you can change it in Excel.

Go to control panel - region and language - first day of week:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that its a complete answer but if you add a column to your data and use +Weekdays, select each date and use type 2, it makes Mondays = 1. You maybe able to sort or filter your data from that.